# Batch file that moves files when string is not in filename or when a file has finish writing

Tags: batch-file

A program is writing flatfiles on a certain directory, the problem is that another program is moving the file before it finishes the writing the flatfile. i have no control on both programs i can only set the path/directory for both so i decided to create a batch file that moves the files when "~" is not in the filename. since temporary files have "~" in their filenames. can you tell me what's wrong with my program?

```
echo off

%%a%% = Dir /b|Find /V "~" (C:\source)

move %%a%% (C:/dest)

pause
```

Any suggestion wouldbe helpful

Thanks!

I tried noodles code

for /f %%A in ('dir /b^|findstr /i /v /c:"~"') do move %%A (C:\dest).

error is

the filename,directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect

im pretty sure the C:\dest exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f %%A in ('dir /b^|findstr /i /v /c:"~"') do echo %%A
```

See `for /?`, `dir /?`, and `findstr /?`.

Comment: thanks i tried it with move for /f %%A in ('dir /b^|findstr /i /v /c:"~"') do move %%A (C:\dest) error is "the filename,directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect"

Comment: You need to specify what you are doing with it, there areall sorts of things to consider - spaces/no spaces - starting directory - etc. I've shown you the general form - but you have to fix it to suit your system. I don't know what this is supposed to do `move %%A (C:\dest)` try `move "%%A" c:\dest`

Comment: thanks the suggestion was perfect. the parenthesis were the problem

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Sadly, your valiant attempt at a solution is more error than not.

Returning to the actual problem - we have a file being created which needs to be moved after it has been created.

The critical question would be - how do we know that creation is complete?

It is *possible* but not *probable* that the file is indeed created as a temporary file, then renamed when complete. It could be that the being-created filename contains `~` but I'd regard the assumption as highly unreliable. `~` occurs frequently in filenames, but very often in short filenames (the 'short' name for a filename that does not follow the 8.3 pattern).

The normal method for creating a file is to open it, write to it, then close it when complete. Might sound obvious, but it's also possible to re-open it and append more data then re-close it, but that would be a relatively rare approach.

In all probability, the open-write-close scenario is used by the creation application. The trick we can use in batch here is that it will appear to have a zero-length until it is closed, hence

```
for /f %%a in (*.*) do if %%~za neq 0 ECHO(move "%%a" "c:\dest\"
```

should work (note that `\` is a directory-separator; `/` is a switch-indicator. Note also that the `move` command is merely `echo`ed - remove the `echo(` to activate the move **after verification**)

If we have the open-write-close-reopen-write_again-close scenario, it becomes more complicated. What we would do then is take a directory list at intervals (say 5 sec or so) and compare it to the previous list. If the filelength of a file remains stable and >0 then that file would seem ready to transfer, if not then wait for the next `dir` snapshot.

Back to OP for verification/comment...

Comment: Thank you for the code i learned a lot from the explanation. the reason i am sure it generates a "`" in the filename is because these are swift messages with long names. but i believe your approach is more valid. Unfortunately, there was an error "the system could not find the file "*.*" Cant seem to display the asterisk on this thread i am running the batch on the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

Launch this in the folder and see what the echo command writes to the console.

```
@ehco off
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /b /a-d^|findstr /v "~" ') do echo move "%%A" "d:\folder"
```